# Calling the free command to deallocate memory crashes my program. Why?

Tags: c, crash, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote a program that encryts and decrypts message using vigenere ciphers. The encrypting part works fine, the problem is the decrypting part: When I want to deallocate the char* using free() my program crashes. When I do not deallocate it, the program works fine and doesn't crash however. 
Here is the program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int main(void) {
    int choice, check, error;
    char ch;
    printf("What do you want to do?\n"
           "1...Decode a message that is saved in a ciphertext.txt file.\n"
           "2...Encode a message and save it in a ciphertext.txt file.\n");
    do {
        error = 0;
        check = scanf("%d%c", &choice, &ch);
        if (check != 2 || ch != '\n' || choice < 1 || choice > 2) {
            printf("Error: Invalid input!\n");
            error = 1;
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (error);
    if (choice == 2) {
        FILE *fp = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "w+");
        char buffer[1000];
        char *p, *q, *r;
        char *encryption_text;
        char *encrypted;
        char *decrypted;
        printf("What are bad characters?\n");
        printf("-Everything except A-Z and a-z.\n");
        printf("Plaintext: ");
        gets(buffer);
        decrypted = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
        strcpy(decrypted, buffer);
        printf("Key: ");
        gets(buffer);
        encryption_text = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
        strcpy(encryption_text, buffer);
        encrypted = (char *)malloc(strlen(decrypted));
        strcpy(encrypted, decrypted);
        putchar('\n');
        p = decrypted;
        q = encryption_text;
        r = encrypted;
        if (strlen(q) > strlen(p)) {
            printf("The key has to be shorter or equal length as the plaintext.");
            return 0;
        }
        while (*p != '\0') {
            if (!(*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') && !(*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')) {
                printf("Bad characters.");
                return 0;
            }
            if (*q == '\0') {
                q = encryption_text;
            } else if (!(*q >= 'A' && *q <= 'Z') && !(*q >= 'a' && *q <= 'z')) {
                printf("Bad characters.");
                return 0;
            }
            if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z') *p -= ' ';
            if (*q >= 'a' && *q <= 'z') *q -= ' ';
            *r = (*p - 'A' + *q - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
            p++;
            q++;
            r++;
        }
        printf("Ciphertext: ");
        puts(encrypted);
        fputs(encryption_text, fp);
        fprintf(fp, ";");
        fputs(encrypted, fp);
        free(decrypted);
        free(encrypted);
        free(encryption_text);
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        FILE *fp = fopen("ciphertext.txt", "r+");
        char buffer[1000];
        char *encryption_text;
        char *encrypted;
        char *decrypted;
        char delimeter[2] = ";";
        char *token;
        char *p, *q, *r;
        fgets(buffer, 1000, fp);
        encrypted = (char *)calloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char), sizeof(char));
        encryption_text = (char *)calloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char), sizeof(char));
        token = strtok(buffer, delimeter);
        strcpy(encryption_text, token);
        encrypted = strrchr(buffer, '\0');
        if (encrypted != NULL) {
            strcpy(encrypted, encrypted + 1);
        }
        decrypted = (char *)calloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char), sizeof(char));
        for (p = decrypted, q = encryption_text, r = encrypted;
                *r != '\0'; p++, r++, q++) {
            if (*q == '\0') {
                q = encryption_text;
            }
            *p = (*r - 'A' - (*q - 'A') + 26) % 26 + 'A';
        }
        printf("Plaintext: ");
        puts(decrypted);
        printf("Key: ");
        puts(encryption_text);
        printf("Ciphertext: ");
        puts(encrypted);
        if (decrypted) free(decrypted);
        if (encrypted) free(encrypted);
        if (encryption_text) free(encryption_text);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can tell me why it crashes. Thanks!

Comment: `decrypted = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));` --> ``decrypted = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);``

Comment: Same for all the other `malloc` calls. You are not allocating space for the string NUL terminator. Which results in memory corruption and hence Undefined Behaviour (including crashes at any point).

Comment: But the buffer has got space for 1000 characters, and all three, decrypted, encrypted and encryption_text, are shorter than the buffer. Aren't they?

Comment: note about `strcpy(encrypted, encrypted + 1);` :  [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) _The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for the crash is probably the following line,

```
    encrypted = strrchr(buffer, '\0');
```

in which you let `encrypted` point somewhere in the memory represented by local variable `buffer`. This is most likely memory on the stack, but at least this memory has not been allocated through `malloc/calloc`.

Hence freeing `encrypted` later on will most likely crash at the `free`-operation.

BTW: as mentioned in the comments, rethink your `malloc/calloc`-statements when using `strcpy` in order to have space for the terminating `'\0'`.

Further, note that `strrchr(buffer, '\0')` returns a pointer to the end of the string contained in `buffer`; copying memory from a position right after the terminating `'\0'` using `strcpy` may be critical, since it is not guaranteed that there will be a second string terminating character.

```
encrypted = strrchr(buffer, '\0');
        if (encrypted != NULL) {
            strcpy(encrypted, encrypted + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was the encrypted = strrchr(buffer, '\0');
I replaced encrypted with a temp char* and then copied temp into encrypted, and now it works. The space missing for the '\0' was not the problem, because the buffer is larger than encrypted, decrypted and encryption_text. Thanks for you help however. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in order to somehow "close" the topic.